# Deserialise a DOM XmlElement to .NET objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dom, xml-deserialization

I have an existing application which manipulates data as an XML DOM model.  I now want to hand that data off to another subsystem as a collection of C# objects.

As far as I can tell, I could serialise the DOM representation to a MemoryStream and the deserialise the stream using an XmlSerializer.  Surely there is a way of processing the DOM representation directly, without the intervening textual representation?  But I can't find it.

How can I use System.Xml.Serialization on a DOM representation?

Comment: Where is this C#?  On the server or running in the browser in some manner?

Comment: I'm not sure what difference that would make - it's C# compiled to run on the .NET framework.  Anyway, the answer is neither - it's a desktop application.  Old-fashioned, I know.

Comment: heh, nm.  When I saw "DOM" I thought you were accessing a browsers DOM with C# and that intrigued me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to project an XmlDocument into a custom collection. You can do this with XmlSerializer.Deserialize but it requires that your XmlDocument have its structure lined up nicely with the collection members.

If this is true then using [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx) is a perfectly fine approach using an `XmlNodeReader`. 
e .g.

```
  XmlDocument xdoc = GetAnXmlDocument();
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeCollection));
  SomeCollection coll = xSerializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xdoc));
```

However if you find that the XmlDocument doesn't line up with your collection you might just want to use [Linq-to-xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and do what ever projection you like.

Comment: That's not quite what I want to do, but 'XmlNodeReader' is indeed what I was missing.  Thanks @conrad!